# Change DataTemplate using visualStateManager in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, datatemplate, visualstatemanager

I want to change my list view's item template using `VisualStateManager`. I have created my `DataTemplate` in my code behind. I want to switch between these 2 templates when orientation changes. How can I create visual state for this? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Just use two ListView with one DataTemplate each and bind their visibility to orientation.

Comment: Is it not possible to use VisualStateManager to change the DataTemplate?